# Com ou sem Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Boa tarde, estou trabalhando... bom, na verdade, estudando PHP e gostaria de trabalhar com as leis brasileiras.

Sei que o trabalho é árduo, porém, mas aos poucos estou conseguindo.

Mas, não sei se utilizo o wordpress como base do site ou se faço só com php.

Pretendo que o site mostre as leis com uma formatação melhor, para ficar mais fácil de entender a sua hierarquia, além de outros recursos que espero conseguir implementar.

Por exemplo, ao visualizar um artigo qualquer, o site informará de qual lei se trata, em qual capítulo está inserido.

Alguém tem alguma opinião ou sugestão?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu particularmente criaria meu próprio programa, com as funcionalidades que eu bem desejar, onde eu desejar.
Mas como você disse que ainda está "estudando" o PHP, o Wordpress deve cair como uma luva, pois reduzirá bastante seu trabalho, pois criar o seu próprio CMS é algo muito bom, mas que exige um certo grau de conhecimento pra não fazer "besteira", o bom uso de OO, PDO (com prepared statements) e um bom projeto MVC, pra não ficar um sistema "desorganizado".

Já com o Wordpress, você tem ótimos plugins, e se já sabe alguma coisa de PHP pode criar seus próprios plugins para as finalidades por você requerida.
Então meu simples conselho é:

Se quiser rapidez e funcionalidades prontas, vá de Worpress, agora se quer algo mais "parrudo" com funcionalidades mais 'complexas' então faça seu próprio CMS, mas lembrando, aconselho que saiba bem o que está fazendo caso escolha a última opção.

Então, agora é contigo!
Boa Sorte!

Answer (score 3):

Se você vai tratar de conteúdos hierárquicos e se eles são bastante numerosos, eu usaria o wordpress, ou algum outro CMS. Pense que, se não, você tem que construir toda a lógica de consulta ao seu conteúdo, e isso pode tomar tempo. Experimente modelar o seu problema usando a lógica do wordpress, e veja se é vantajoso ou não